# Understanding where pg_toast is coming from

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I've got a fair amount of storage in pg_toast

```
             relation             |  size
----------------------------------+---------
 pg_toast.pg_toast_43934449       | 87 GB
 pg_toast.pg_toast_43934438       | 64 GB
 pg_toast.pg_toast_50877          | 35 GB
 pg_toast.pg_toast_16715          | 15 GB
 pg_toast.pg_toast_16813          | 13 GB
 pg_toast.pg_toast_5706469        | 1335 MB
 pg_toast.pg_toast_43934449_index | 1004 MB
 pg_toast.pg_toast_43934438_index | 942 MB
 pg_toast.pg_toast_16715_index    | 709 MB
 pg_toast.pg_toast_16813_index    | 548 MB
 pg_toast.pg_toast_50877_index    | 530 MB
 pg_toast.pg_toast_3518414        | 463 MB
 pg_toast.pg_toast_16994          | 339 MB
 pg_toast.pg_toast_46608          | 310 MB
 pg_toast.pg_toast_16994_index    | 92 MB
 pg_toast.pg_toast_22345124       | 68 MB
 pg_toast.pg_toast_46608_index    | 51 MB
 pg_toast.pg_toast_437018         | 43 MB
 pg_toast.pg_toast_5706469_index  | 15 MB
 pg_toast.pg_toast_3518414_index  | 13 MB
(20 rows)
```

Which is significant when the total size of the DB is currently about 420GB. This is totally expected as some of my tables are storing JSON as either `text` type (for some of my older tables) or `jsonb` for some of the newer ones.

A lot of these columns can be cleaned up at the application-level by just deleting some older data. The problem is that it's hard to know what's actually contributing to the pg_toast tables?

How can I reverse-trace a pg_toast to the actual row/column reference of another table?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use this query to find out all tables with TOAST tables:

```
SELECT oid::regclass,
       reltoastrelid::regclass,
       pg_relation_size(reltoastrelid) AS toast_size
FROM pg_class
WHERE relkind = 'r'
  AND reltoastrelid <> 0
ORDER BY 3 DESC;
```

To find out which of the columns in the table consumes most space, you could try a query like

```
SELECT sum(length(col1)) AS col1_size,
       sum(length(col2)) AS col2_site
FROM some_table;
```

Here `col1` and `col2` would be `text`, `varchar`, `char` or `bytea` columns, which are usually the largest ones. With other data types like `jsonb` you could cast to `text` to get an estimate.

Answer (score 6):

Internally, postgres identifies pretty much everything by oids - the numeric part of your TOAST table names should be the identifier of the *parent* table:

From [PostgreSQL.org](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/6624.1481672778@sss.pgh.pa.us)

> ... the numeric part of the toast table's name is the OID of its parent, so really you
>   just need to do
>
> select '43934449'::regclass ;
>
> Confirming the reltoastrelid link is a good idea though.